# What supporting documents to send along grad school application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

when applying to grad schools most university portals allow applicants to upload additional documents; I would like to know how can applicants make use of this opportunity and add documents to alter their status in the admission process.
though this question might be considered as not having a specific answer I must say: what type of content can be added to be considered useful. e.g. Drafts of manuscripts, research proposal (if it is not included in the required documents), other related works (such as projects, dataset, tools etc.), and CV (if not included in the required documents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask them. I very much doubt there is a uniform document package requirement. If you come from a different country, the documents they'd want to see might be quite a bit more detailed than if you come from the same country.

Comment: there is no specific school or department to ask them, and it's mostly by your choice. and I don't think being a foreigner affects details of a document.

Comment: @adelrahimi, ask the school where you are applying to. They asked me for specific documents (including proof of being able to pay for the program and support myself) that I assume aren't required for US citizens. It was a long time ago, I'm not clear on details.